# How can I make a left join and bring only the first row that follows a certain condition?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, amazon-redshift

For instance, I have this dataset with the price of the product and the date the price was updated:

```
category      price       update_date
A             100         2020-01-01
A             120         2020-05-10
A             140         2020-05-15
B             150         2020-01-01
B             200         2020-03-01
```

and this dataset with the sales and the date they were made:

```
sale_id     category      sales_date  
1           A             2020-02-01
2           A             2020-03-01    
3           B             2020-02-04 
4           B             2020-03-09
```

I want to know which price was applied in each sale. So I need to get the last price update and input in the second dataset. So I have to bring the first update_date that is higher than the sales_date. I would get the following dataset as a result:

```
sale_id     category      sales_date     price
1           A             2020-02-01     100
2           A             2020-05-12     120    
3           B             2020-02-04     150
4           B             2020-03-09     200
```

Any thoughts? I think I would have to do something like this [Finding the lowest value in a table greater than a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769069/finding-the-lowest-value-in-a-table-greater-than-a-certain-value), but I'm still not sure how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can handle this by adding an end date for each update and then using `join`:

```
select s.*, u.price
from sales s left join
     (select u.*,
             lead(update) over (partition by category order by update_date) as next_update_date
      from updates u
     ) u
     on s.category = u.category and
        s.sales_date >= u.update_date and
        (s.sales_date < u.next_update_date or u.next_udpate_date is null)
```